# Drawing a 'safe path' onto a UIImageView in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiimageview

I want to create a view with a `UIImageView` inside it, where the user can draw a circle on a specific area of the `UIImageView`. Then, the view clears once they have finished drawing and when they draw again, if the drawing is inside the last drawing's circle, an alert appears saying 'Correct'.

How can this be done? I've already looked at projects like [this](https://github.com/stkim1/MTImageMapView), but I haven't managed to find out how to actually draw the boundaries and set an if statement up to decide whether the user is drawing within or outside the boundaries on their second drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a `UIBezierPath` of the "safe" area, you can then use the method `containsPoint:` which returns: (quote from [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html))

> YES if the point is considered to be within the path’s enclosed area
>   or NO if it is not.

you would probably need to detect touches and check each touch point

Comment: How can I get the boundaries of the 'circle' once it has been drawn to make these checks?

Comment: you can create a UIBezierPath from the set of touches used to draw the first circle, look at the `addLineToPoint:` method as a first step